# Did I kill my plants?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

I live in Brazil. I have a 52 gallon tank. It has small common species such as molly. The PH is very alkaline(7.5 - 8). The fish are healthy. I bought some plants: elodeas(Egeria densa). They were growing fast and becoming tall. Some reached out the surface.

But a lot of snails showed up. Uncountable snails. I killed some that were on the glass, however there were a lot, so I went to the store and bought a product that has `Copper Sulfate, and Iron Sulfate` on its composition. The salesman said to apply one drop for each 5 five liters. So I did it, for three times, with 24 hour between each application.

After that the plants start to die. The leaves became brown and are falling.

I think the product is the cause because they were healthy and growing so much before that.

Someone knows if the mentioned elements of the product would be the cause?

Comment: As I understand it, you bough plants at a store that contaminated your tank with snails, then went to the same store and bought a product to control the snail, which then killed the plants.  Maybe you need to look for a different store?

Comment: Yeap! Same store. I've never thought that.

Comment: And to get rid of the snails, it's better to get some Assassin snails: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clea_helena Much better then adding chemicals to your tank.

Answer (score 2):

At least Copper Sulfate is a possible cause of the plants' degeneration. [NPIC](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/cuso4gen.html) has this to say about Copper Sulfate:

> Copper sulfate is an inorganic compound that combines sulfur with copper. It can kill bacteria, algae, roots, plants, snails, and fungi.

Copper Sulfate is also used to [kill roots](http://www.coppersulfatecrystals.com/killroots.html) in sewer lines. Presumably if it can kill roots, it is not very good for plants.